# Loop to concatenate tsv files R

Tags: r

I have the names of the files I want to concatenate:
files<-c("test/df1.tsv" "test/df2.tsv")

I have x2 .tsv files that look like so (sorry -  I didn't know how to code this into an reproducible, example df):

df1

[image: df1]

df2

[image: df2]

I am trying to concatenate these tsv files by column.
I have managed to read some blogs and have got so far as using map:

```
metrics_df <- map_df(files, read_tsv)
```

But this is doing an rbind like so:

```
metrics_df
# A tibble: 22 × 4
   metric_1       ...2    ...3   ...4  
   <chr>          <chr>   <chr>  <chr> 
 1 Reads          P1014B  P1014F P1036A
 2 Family_Size    2677    1021   879   
 3 Uni_Counts     0.1     1      1     
 4 metric_2       NA      NA     NA    
 5 Reads          P1014B  P1014F P1036A
 6 Median_Size    2677    1021   879   
 7 Aligned_Counts 0.1     1      1     
 8 metric_3       NA      NA     NA    
 9 Reads          P1014B  P1014F P1036A
10 Target_Counts  2677    1021   879   
11 Target_PCT     0.1     1      1     
12 Reads          P10111B P1456F P847A 
13 Family_Size    556     671    1012  
14 Uni_Counts     0.1     0.8    0.1   
15 metric_2       NA      NA     NA    
16 Reads          P10111B P1456F P847A 
17 Median_Size    2677    1021   879   
18 Aligned_Counts 0.1     1      1     
19 metric_3       NA      NA     NA    
20 Reads          P10111B P1456F P847A 
21 Target_Counts  2677    1021   879   
22 Target_PCT     0.1     1      1
```

I would like to combine the files so that the columns are the concatenated 'reads' row.

Is there a way of doing this with map() or alternatively splitting the df using dplyr???

Comment: you can concatenate side by side with `map_dfc`
Further processing must be specified

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df <- list.files(path='$YOUR_FILES_PATH') %>% 
 lapply(read_tsv) %>% 
 bind_rows
```